# Why does my time series data frame restrict the number of time steps I'd like to use in my LSTM?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, lstm, reshape

I need help understanding how exactly I'm permitted to reshape the input data for my LSTM. First, my time series data is in the form of a Pandas data frame:

[image]

It has the following shape: `(36356, 9)`. I split my dataframe into train and test sets such as the following: `X_train.shape = (29084, 7)`, `X_test.shape = (7272, 7)`, `y_train.shape = (29084,)`, and `y_test.shape = (7272,)`.

Question 1: I know I must reshape the 2D X-data into 3D as `(samples/rows, timesteps, features)`. But do I have to reshape the y-data into 3D, too?

Question 2:  For the X-data and y-data, I know that the array values of their 2D shapes must match the array values of their 3D shapes. So suppose I reshape my X_train data into `(29084, 1, 7)` and my X_test data into `(7272, 1, 7)`. The factors for `X_train.shape[0]` are `1, 2, 4, 7271, 14542, and X_train.shape[0]`. The factors for `X_test.shape[0]` are `1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24, ..., 3636, and X_test.shape[0]`. The common factors are `1, 2, and 4`. So my dataset only permits me to have the possible timesteps of 1, 2, and 4, correct? That is, I must reshape both my X_train.shape[0] and X_test.shape[0] to be divided by the same number of timesteps, correct. And similarly true for y_train.shape[0] and y_test.shape[0]?

Question 3: If I can have larger timesteps, how else am I permitted to reshape the X-data and y-data?

If it helps, my LSTM is constructed as follows:

```
batch_size = X_train.shape[0]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True, stateful = False), 
                                        input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
es = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 3)
                  
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['Recall'])
                  
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = 360, verbose = 0, 
                          callbacks = [es], validation_data = (X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your timestep in your data? reshaping x_train to (batch, 1, 7) means that the timestep = 1 which is of no use to RNN. I would suggest to look at the data and understand what is the value that is changing over time ?

Comment: My time series data is indexed by the minute—meaning that each row in the data frame is separated by a minute. Moreover, it's a binary classification problem in which I'm using the data to predict whether a device is on or off at each minute. I've now added the original data frame above.

Comment: It seems like the the first dimension of your data i.e. 36356 is your timestep dimension. Which means that you have 1 input data with 36356 timstep records each with 7 features. So to feed into the RNN your shape should be (1, 36356, 7)

Comment: Furthermore you can breakup 36356 rows into smaller parts, that way you can increase you batch number - for example, 64 batches of 568 rows i.e. shape becomes (64, 568, 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras LSTM input shape ([Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2)):

> ```
> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]
> ```

**Answer 1:**

No, you don't have to reshape y-data, as it represents your output shape of your whole model not the output of your LSTM layer. The shape of y-data should however correspond to the output of the last layer of your model, which from your code it already does. However if you divide your data into smaller batches, your y-data should reflect that.

**Answer 2:**

It seems like the the first dimension of your data i.e. 36356 is your timestep dimension. Which means that you have 1 input timeseries data with 36356 timstep records each with 7 features. So to feed into the RNN your shape should be (1, 36356, 7).

Furthermore you can breakup 36356 rows into smaller parts, that way you can increase you batch number - for example, 64 batches of 568 rows i.e. shape becomes (64, 568, 7).  However this would also require you divide your y-data into smaller batches as well.

**Answer 3:**

You can just wrap your current 2D array in another array making it 3D i.e. (1, 36356, 7).

Comment: Thank you! You are a tremendous help. To clarify some last-minute questions on my part: my X_train is originally shaped as (29084, 7); so I should reshape as (1, 29084, 7); my X_test is originally shaped as (7272, 7); so I should reshape as (1, 7272, 7), correct? Similarly, my y_train should remain its original shape of (29084, 1), and my y_test should remain its original shape of (7272, 1) because my output layer is Dense(1), correct? Of course, I would have to change things accordingly if I would include batches.

Comment: Yes you are correct on all your questions. You can reshape your array with the `np.expand_dims()` method.

Comment: Darn. I got the following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0aa3297ed2f5> in <module>
     15 # Fitting the model
     16 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 360, verbose = 2, 
---> 17                     callbacks = [es], validation_data = (X_test, y_test), shuffle = True)

ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 27932 target samples.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment about the error, my X_train is shaped (1, 27932, 7), my X_test is shaped (1, 6984, 7), my y_train is shaped (27932, 1), and my y_test is shaped (6984, 1). But the error seems to be pointing at the fact that these are not the right shapes.

Comment: My bad. You would need to change your Y-data as well. To the model, its getting 1 batch of data as input, but for output it thinks it is getting 7272 batches of data. You should wrap your Y-data as well in another array. Sorry :(

Comment: Not a problem. I tried reshaping the y_train as (1, 27932, 1) and the y_test as (1, 6984, 1), to match the X_train and X_test, but I got another ValueError: Error when checking input: expected bidirectional_input to have shape (27932, 7) but got array with shape (6984, 7). The error points to my validation data in my model.fit line.

Comment: Try setting `return_sequences=False` in the 2nd LSTM `model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences = True)))`. The `return_sequences=True` returns the hidden state which is used by subsequent LSTM layers, but you don't have a 3rd LSTM

Comment: I got the following ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 27932, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222671/discussion-between-mb0850-and-ashton-t-sperry).